# How to connect/listen to nsqd from a webserver

Tags: python, python-3.x, nsq

So I have a simple flask server and wanted to listen to nsqd,(My nsqd and nsqlookupd dockers are running fine.) I'm using gnsq from python as a tool to achieve that

server.py:

```
from flask import Flask
import gnsq

consumer = gnsq.Consumer('test_topic', 'test_channel', '0.0.0.0:4161')

@consumer.on_message.connect
def handler(consumer, message):
    print ('got message:', message.body)

consumer.start()

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Flasky"
```

and when I run the server all I get is

`[0.0.0.0:4161] connection failed (NSQSocketError(57, 'Socket is not connected'))`

I tried changing ports as well but still persist.